# Deleting row from database using _id column in context menu from ListView

Tags: android

I have a listview which is populated by a `SimpleCursorAdapter` that is binding data to the view from a cursor from a sqlite database. I would like to have a context menu option to delete the a list item when it is long pressed, so I register the ListView for a context menu by calling `registerForContextMenu(historyListView)`. I've been trying to remove the row from the database by getting the row id in `OnCreateContextMenu` and storing it as a private field called `lastSelectedId`, then if the remove context item is selected in `OnContextItemSelected`, removing the row from the database by checking the `_id` column against `lastSelectedId`.

This isn't working.

So - 
(1.) is the row as given by

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
        lastSelectedId = info.id;
```

the same as the _id column in the database?

and (2.) if not, how else can I delete the item in `onContextItemSelected()` based on the `_id` of the row in the database?

EDIT: Sorry about not explaining why this approach wasn't working more in-depth: What happens is that nothing happens when I attempt to delete the row: I call `mDB.delete(DB_TABLENAME,"_id=" + lastSelectedId, null);` on the database and then I call `bookmarksListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` on my `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Then I see no change in the entries in my listview, which differs from my expected behavior that the row which I called remove on will disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I needed to re-do the cursor after the database was changed (for some reason I had thought that this would be done automatically - my mistake) `bookmarksDbCursor.requery()` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

When you say it isn't working, what isn't working? Does it not delete the entry? Does it not display the updated list? How are you deleting the row? Can you share some more code?

In general, id is generally the _id of the database (if you use the standard conventions). Are you using your own content provider? You need to notify system that the database changed so it can be requeried - this is typically done if you followed the ContentProvider samples from the SDK (look at notifyChange), and if you use a managed query.

Comment: "id is generally the _id of the database"  
Thanks - that narrows down the problem a little. I've edited my post to be more specific about what I'm doing to remove the row, but I'm still not sure if the entry is being removed from the database or not. I definitely know that the list isn't updated at all.

Comment: You can look at your database with sqlite3 - if it's on the phone, use adb shell, go to where the database is (/data/data/your_app/databases), and call it with "sqlite3" and use .dump to get the full contents. Then, add a Log.d() before you delete to print out lastSelectedId to see what ID you're actually trying to delete.